# Spring Boot + JPA + Hibernate - BeanCreationException

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, spring-boot, vaadin

I am currently working on a project in Vaadin with Spring Boot and I want to reuse some repositories from another project without adding that project as a dependency, but when I try to run the project I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataCache': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myproject.vas.aftersales.repository.AfterSalesFileRepository com.myproject.vas.DataCache.afterSalesFileRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'afterSalesFileRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

I have searched the web for solutions and tried everything I could find from switching packages to changing dependency versions to ...

My repository:

```
@Component
public interface AfterSalesFileRepository extends JpaRepository<AfterSalesFile, Integer> {

    @Query("select m from AfterSalesFile m " +
            "where m.id=:id and m.status is not 'INACTIVE'")
    AfterSalesFile findOne(@Param("id") final Integer id);
}
```

The class that tries to initialise and use the repository:

```
@Component
public class DataCache {

    @Getter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private CustomerIdentityRepository customerIdentityRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AfterSalesFileRepository afterSalesFileRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DataCache(CustomerIdentityRepository customerIdentityRepository) {
        this.customerIdentityRepository = customerIdentityRepository;

    }

...

    public List<AfterSalesFile> getAllAftersales() {
        return afterSalesFileRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

My databaseconfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver jpaPropertyResolver;
    @Autowired(required = false)
    private PersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.jpaPropertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, "spring.jpa.");
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("jdbcTemplate")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        if (persistenceUnitManager != null) {
            entityManagerFactoryBean
                    .setPersistenceUnitManager(persistenceUnitManager);
        }
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.myproject.vas.aftersales");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().putAll(jpaPropertyResolver.getSubProperties("properties."));
        Map<String, Object> properties = entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap();
        properties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty("hibernate.naming-strategy", SpringNamingStrategy.class.getName()));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto", "none"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false"));
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

My main:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.myproject.vas.aftersales.repository"})
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myproject"})
    public class VasApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(VasApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

My POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    ...

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Vaadin -->
        ... Vaadin dependencies

        <!-- hibernate dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <!--<version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**UPDATE**

mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:tree (default-cli) @ infopoint ---
[INFO] com.asadventure:infopoint:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.asadventure:customer-service:jar:crm-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-all:jar:1.0.0.M4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-config:jar:1.0.0.M4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul:jar:1.0.0.M4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery:jar:1.0.0.M4:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-core:jar:1.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.asadventure:LoggingUtils:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.asadventure:job-fetch-interface:jar:crm-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.asadventure:data-utils:jar:crm-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework.data:spring-cql:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:1.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-metrics-event-stream:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-javanica:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-ribbon:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-core:jar:0.20.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.netflix.zuul:zuul-core:jar:1.0.28:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.19.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.dozer:dozer:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-dse:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-mapping:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.stratio.cassandra:cassandra-lucene-index-builder:jar:2.2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.6.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ecwid.consul:consul-api:jar:1.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-core:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-transport:jar:2.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.reactivex:rxnetty-contexts:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty-servo:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-httpclient:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.13:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.13:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:jar:1.11:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-commons-util:jar:0.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-loadbalancer:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-statistics:jar:0.1.1:runtime
[INFO] +- com.asadventure:customer-service-client:jar:docker-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-consul-config:jar:1.0.0.M4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-consul-discovery:jar:1.0.0.M4:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-consul-core:jar:1.0.0.M4:compile
[INFO] +- com.asadventure:wso2-filter:jar:abeq-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-server:jar:7.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vaadin:vaadin-sass-compiler:jar:0.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.vaadin.external.flute:flute:jar:1.3.0.gg2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.yahoo.platform.yui:yuicompressor:jar:2.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- rhino:js:jar:1.7R2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vaadin:vaadin-shared:jar:7.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.vaadin.external.streamhtmlparser:streamhtmlparser-jsilver:jar:0.0.10.vaadin1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:guava:jar:16.0.1.vaadin1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiled:jar:7.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin:vaadin-spring:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:jar:7.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.vaadin:viritin:jar:1.39:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.vaadin.addon:confirmdialog:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.commonjava.googlecode.markdown4j:markdown4j:jar:2.2-cj-1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:grid-renderers-collection-addon:jar:0.92:compile
[INFO] +- de.datenhahn.vaadin:componentrenderer:jar:0.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- cglib:cglib:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.11.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.16:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.13:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.13:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.4.1:compile
```

We already have a Cassandra db running and this would add a mssql db. A colleague pointed out it tries to Cassandra instead of the mssql:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:185) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.CassandraRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraRepositoryFactoryBean.java:62) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
```

Comment: Can you post the whole POM? Have you defined any properties with version numbers? The output of `mvn dependency:tree` would also be helpful.

Comment: We extend from a parent-pom, so the current doesn't have any versions. I added the dependency tree though!

Comment: For starters stop mixing spring versions... You have 4.1.6 and 4.2.3 classes that isn't going to work (you are also mixing boot 1.2.3 and 1.3.0). Make sure you are using the appropriate versions for Spring boot. (Also wondering why are you manually configuring the entitymanagerfactory instead of using the auto configured one? There is nothing you configure that isn't automatically configured?

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractMethodError` is in virtually every case a result of non-matching dependencies. When two libraries with incompatible versions end up on the classpath `AbstractMethodError` can occur.

In your case the problem is likely caused by the several persistence-related dependencies you have specified. By default you should not be specifying JPA/Hibernate dependencies when using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

If you check [this tutorial](https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-web-application-part-3-spring-data-jpa/) for example, you will see that the [final pom](https://github.com/springframeworkguru/springbootwebapp/blob/part3/pom.xml) for the running application only contains a driver jar (h2) included other than the boot-starter dependency for persistence.

Comment: I tried removing all JPA/Hibernate dependencies, but I still get the same error sadly enough. I even tried adding another driver jar like you proposed. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: Do not add anything new. Just drop those 3 and leave these two: spring-boot-starter-data-jpa & sqljdbc4.

Comment: Still nothing, but it's probably a step in the right way.

Comment: Can you post a full list of jars from your WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Does a spring boot project have a WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Uhh, sorry. I thought you had a web app. Your classpath then. Lib folder, or any other means you make your dependencies available for java.

Comment: Added dependency tree and additional info!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing @Component from AfterSalesFileRepository. If you have @ComponentScan enable than spring boot will automatically create repository implementations for any interface which extends JpaRepository

Answer (score 0):

When you look at your dependency tree you will see that you are mixing versions of Spring Boot jars from Spring Boot 1.2.3 and 1.3.0. Never mix versions. Due to this you also mix versions of Spring 4.1.6 and 4.2.3 which is always dangerous.

For starters remove the `spring-data-jpa`, `hibernate` and `spring-security` dependencies and use the starter for Spring Security (`spring-boot-starter-security`) instead of manually adding the dependencies. (The starters bring in the appropriate versions).

Also remove the `spring-test` and `junit` dependencies and use `spring-boot-starter-test` with `<scope>test</scope>` as a dependency.

Next something is pulling in a `spring-boot-starter-log4j` for spring boot 1.2.3 fix this to use the proper version for your boot version.

You also want to use cassandra again use the starter `spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra` for this.

There is also an old `spring-security-crypto` jar being pulled in (3.2.7 instead of 4.0.3) which will also lead to getting older dependencies for other jars.

Using the starters saves you from specifying the versions (or can keep you from adding the wrong versions).

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Vaadin -->
    ... Vaadin dependencies

    <!-- hibernate dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        
</dependencies>
```